# How to debug Widget Xcode 12

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, xcode12, widgetkit

How to debug Widgets (WidgetKit) on Xcode 12?

For example, setting breakpoints or at least making `print` statements work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Debug`, `Attach to process by PID or Name…`

In the process name field, enter you widget target name. Then, run your widget target.